# How to access non_public_metrics field in twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to retrieve the information within the `non_public_metrics` field in twitter API (i.e, "impression_count", "url_link_clicks", "user_profile_clicks"). I was able to access the `public_metrics` field using only the Bearer Token. But, when I include the `non_public_metrics` in my `query params` I got the error `Field Authorization Error`. Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import collections
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def auth():
    return os.getenv('TWITTER_TOKEN')

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers

def create_url(keyword, start_date, end_date, max_results = 10):
    ttid = 1184334528837574656
    search_url = f"https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{ttid}/tweets" #Change to the endpoint you want to collect data from

    #change params based on the endpoint you are using
    query_params = {'start_time': start_date,
                    'end_time': end_date,
                    'max_results': max_results,
                    'tweet.fields': 'public_metrics,created_at,non_public_metric',#remove non_public_metric and the code will work
                    'next_token': {}}
    
    return (search_url, query_params)

def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params, next_token = None):
    params['next_token'] = next_token   #params object received from create_url function
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, params = params)
    print("Endpoint Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

#Inputs for the request
bearer_token = auth()
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
keyword = "xbox lang:en"

start_time = "2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
end_time = "2021-12-22T00:00:00.000Z"

max_results = 100
url = create_url(keyword, start_time,end_time, max_results)

json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1])

print(json_response['data']) #if non_public_metrics is included, this throws a error
```

Then I read in [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics) that I need to use OAuth1.0 authorization in order to access the field `non_public_metrics`. I tried to use one of the sample codes available in twitter-dev [GH'page](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code) that uses OAuth1.0 authentication. Here is the snippet I used:

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os
import json

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

consumer_key = os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret = os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET")

#I actually used an ID associate to my account, not this one
params = {"ids": "1184334528837574656", "tweet.fields": "public_metrics,created_at,non_public_metrics"}

request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
        "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )

resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)

# Get authorization
base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)
verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: ")

# Get the access token
access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
    resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
    verifier=verifier,
)
oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)


access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]

# Make the request
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

response = oauth.get(
    "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", params=params
)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
    )

print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))
json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This snippet, however, leads me to a similar error `"Sorry, you are not authorized to access 'non_public_metrics.impression_count' on the Tweet with ids`. Besides, this snippet has the huge incovenient of ask me to click a link and generate a PIN every time I need to request information for a particular tweet.

How can I properly request information on `non_public_metrics` field for my tweets?

Comment: I'm trying to understand here, is the Tweet for which you want the metrics for, originally posted by the account that you are authenticating as? This is not clear from your post.

Comment: Yes! I retrieve the tweets IDs of the account I want the metrics for and use one of them to test the second snippet. The id 1184334528837574656 is a random id used in the snippet just as an example. The tokens (`bearer token`, `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`) are also from the account I want the metrics for. Only the PIN I generate without login into account of interest (I just copy the token value in the url after clicked at it and give permission), since I don't have direct access to the company twitter account.

Comment: now that you asked, the error is probably due to the way the PIN is being generated. But is there a way to pull the data from the non_public_metrics field without having to generate this PIN?

Comment: no, you need to go through the PIN authentication process (*with* access to the Twitter account you are authenticating) to get back a valid access token. These private metrics values are only available to the owning account.

Answer (score 1):

One can retrieve the information within the non_public_metrics field using the url `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/[YOU_TWEET_ID]?tweet.fields=non_public_metrics` in Postman. To do the same in python just use the following snippet:

```py
import os
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import requests

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

YOUR_TWEET_ID = ''

url = f'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/{YOUR_TWEET_ID}?tweet.fields=public_metrics,non_public_metrics'

CONSUMER_KEY=os.getenv('CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET=os.getenv('CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_TOKEN=os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')
ACCESS_SECRET=os.getenv('ACCESS_SECRET')

headeroauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, signature_type='auth_header')
r = requests.get(url, auth=headeroauth)

print(r.json())
```